# Strange errors in MikTeX when using algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

I am trying to use the `algorithm2e` package in MikTeX,
but when I put these commands:

```
\dontprintsemicolon
\SetLine
```

it doesn't recognize them. I do not understand why;
I have used these commands before in another machine
without a problem. The package `algorithm2e` is installed:
I checked in the package manager and the directory and
it appears to be installed.

Comment: You should post a [complete (but minimal) example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), to show us what you're trying to do. Also check which version of the relevant packages you have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to replace them with

```
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetAlgoLined
```

I think that at some point of time (version 4.0 and newer) the old syntax was removed.  You can also try to pass the `oldcommands` option to the package, which should enable the old form of the commands.

Comment: This works.. but I hate having to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Debian and Ubuntu did not update their `texlive-science` package for the latest version of `algorithm2e`. So if you are using `algorithm2e` and compiling your LaTeX documents on Windows and Linux environment you will bumb to this problem constantly. Simply changing the commands does not help much, since you need to change it everytime you change platform.

My usual solution is to include definitions for new versions of the `algorithm2e` commands:

```
\providecommand{\SetAlgoLined}{\SetLine}
\providecommand{\DontPrintSemicolon}{\dontprintsemicolon}
```

Thus, when using old version of the package (Linux) new versions of the commands are defined. If the new version of the package is used and these commands are already defined (Windows), `\providecommand` directives are simply ignored by MiKTeX.

You can write these commands into a seperate file and include it whenever your document will use `algorithm2e` and will constantly be compiled at multiple platforms.

Do not forget these commands should be inserted/included **after** the `\usepackage[...]{algorithm2e}` stuff.